# What is the reason, that rendering same HAML is much slower when ajax than loading in Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Short description (we are in browsers debugger network tab):

```
AJAX GET /page/42 takes ~20s
replay/resend this XHR takes ~15s
open this XHR in new tab takes ~1.5s (only!)
replay/resend this XHR takes ~15s (again)
```

- Happens in development only
- is always (and cross browser) reproduce able
- Rails 3.2.22.5
- Time is lost in HAML (very sure)

I am working on an HTML editor to design pages for printing. This editor is - let's say - comprehensive.

When starting I have to render the complete editors HAML (~ 1000 lines) this takes less than 5s (unless first after rails start). This is fairly fast.

The basic structure looks like this (pseudo HAML, each line is a partial,  numbers are ~rendering time) section count (n) is typically around 10 to 15

```
editor_layout 
    editor (~5s)
        edit_background (~1.5s)
            the_page (0.1s*n)
                section_1
                .
                .
                section_n
        dialog_1                            
        dialog_2
        .
        .
        dialog_42
```

when printing (PDF) it looks like

```
print_layout (~1.5s) 
    the_page (0.1s*n)
        section_1
        .
        .
        section_n
```

So far so good and OK especially while in a development environment.

But when I have to change the page in editor and call the new page with AJAX to get just the inner HTML

```
no_layout
    edit_background (~15s)
        the_page (1s*n)
            section_1
            .
            .
            section_n
```

the action takes about 15s (!). The time comes from rendering a section takes now 1 second instead of 100ms. If I open the same URL in a new browser tab I am back to the usual 1.5 seconds.

I have no idea why.

To make it even weirder:

I can reload (re-render) any (HTML) part of the editor with AJAX, this looks like

```
/page/42/edit?inner-html=background, dialog_1, dialog_42
/page/42/edit?inner-html=dialog_5
```

In this case, the editor HAML is rendered but only the part(s) requested, and if I request (AJAX)

```
/page/42/edit?inner-html=background
```

I am back to ~2 seconds! although there is much more and complex logic executed.

I have no idea where to search further, but I want to understand whats going on.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: put the console output

Explanation: these to logs I took after several open in tab and refresh and replay XHR

I had to delete some (identical SQL-) lines because of 30k limit

lines looking like this

```
-------            start        5   (     5)  [xxxxx  number]
```

are the output of a "timeline" method. Where start (in this case 'start') is just a name, the number is the time (ms) since the last call and in parenthesis is the time so far.  The optional "XXXX number" tells the time for a named block call.

Comparing these two files shows the difference in line "start with paragroup" and this is the first line in HAML:

```
- time_line "start with paragroup"
```

while "done prepare_paragroup" is more or less the last before rendering "paragroup"

log of the tab(refresh)

```
--- render if @ [@]
--- render if message_box - not rendered  [@]


Started GET "/ldc/books/288efbc2-98b2-4beb-92de-e5de108cec4d/draw/8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c23-9de3-e7c7ee939fd5?inner=@" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-16 19:31:28 +0300
    -------                       initialize        0   (     0)
Processing by Ldc::BooksController#draw as HTML
  Parameters: {"inner"=>"@", "id"=>"288efbc2-98b2-4beb-92de-e5de108cec4d", "bookpage_id"=>"8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c23-9de3-e7c7ee939fd5"}
say in site_controller.rb:(66) block
            ------- start --------
    -------                            start        5   (     5)
  LoginData Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "login_data".* FROM "login_data" WHERE "login_data"."id" = '0c439950-b8d6-4b8a-9d39-2b2e51a4a291' LIMIT 1
say in checker.rb:(16) initialize
  Ldc::Person Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_people".* FROM "ldc_people" WHERE "ldc_people"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_people"."login_data_id" = '0c439950-b8d6-4b8a-9d39-2b2e51a4a291' LIMIT 1
  Ldc::Bookpage Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "ldc_bookpages".* FROM "ldc_bookpages" WHERE "ldc_bookpages"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_bookpages"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c23-9de3-e7c7ee939fd5"]]
    -------  call ldc/editor/edit_background        1   (   265)
######
{:locals=>{}}
{:locals=>{}}
    -------        call ldc/editor/book_page       53   (   319)
    -------     start render partial book_page (#<Ldc::PageTemplates::Defau       27   (   346)
    -------    --ClassicDefaultDefault---- start bookpage 8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c2        0   (   346)
    -------               start to css pre:         0   (   346)
    -------                     done analyse        0   (   346)
    -------           done cibo_template.css        2   (   348)
    -------                           555555        1   (   349)
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup        1   (   350)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup       13   (   363)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup        0   (   363)
    -------           render partial group:         0   (   363)
    -------             start with paragroup       80   (   443)
   (1.0ms)  select textable_id as id, role, text
...
    -------               end with paragroup       12   (   455)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (29.4ms)
    -------              done partial group:        1   (   456)          group     93
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup        0   (   456)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup       15   (   471)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup        1   (   472)
    -------             start with paragroup       66   (   539)
    -------               end with paragroup       20   (   559)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (20.1ms)
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup        0   (   560)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup       16   (   576)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup        0   (   576)
    -------             start with paragroup       67   (   643)
    -------               end with paragroup        7   (   650)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (7.0ms)
  Ldc::Pageelement Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pageelements".* FROM "ldc_pageelements" WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pageelements"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "da4584dd-ea18-4f14-a321-1e2628efe0c9"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (1.0ms)  UPDATE "ldc_pageelements" SET "element_position" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2017-08-16 16:31:29.294182', "paragroup_order" = '211cfcc6-3ce5-4c3f-b001-2230a76cc8903568750-4cc5-45ca-879e-1fa214921d12' WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."id" = 'da4584dd-ea18-4f14-a321-1e2628efe0c9'
   (4.0ms)  commit transaction
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup        9   (   659)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup       22   (   681)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup        1   (   682)
    -------             start with paragroup       64   (   747)
    -------               end with paragroup       11   (   758)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (12.1ms)
  Ldc::Pageelement Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pageelements".* FROM "ldc_pageelements" WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pageelements"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "a27f1ca2-d136-4aef-a486-24772766c04f"]]
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
   (1.0ms)  UPDATE "ldc_pageelements" SET "element_position" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2017-08-16 16:31:29.403252', "paragroup_order" = 'dd7489ce-0b22-40dc-81ab-072de59b7357' WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."id" = 'a27f1ca2-d136-4aef-a486-24772766c04f'
   (5.0ms)  commit transaction
  Ldc::Pageelement Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pageelements".* FROM "ldc_pageelements" WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pageelements"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "9e09e934-50a7-41eb-94df-7355b1d3306c"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (1.0ms)  UPDATE "ldc_pageelements" SET "element_position" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2017-08-16 16:31:29.412301', "paragroup_order" = '' WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."id" = '9e09e934-50a7-41eb-94df-7355b1d3306c'
   (4.0ms)  commit transaction
    -------    done   get_page_elements_html       20   (   778)
  Ldc::Page Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pages".* FROM "ldc_pages" WHERE "ldc_pages"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pages"."id" = 'dcc8a707-c1c4-4f68-9973-e4c7f0746546' LIMIT 1
  Rendered ldc/editor/_book_page.haml (440.4ms)
    -------        call ldc/editor/book_page        4   (   782)           page    463
    -------               start to css pre:         0   (   782)
    -------                     done analyse        1   (   783)
    -------               start to css pre:         0   (   783)
    -------                     done analyse        8   (   791)
    -------  start get_page_editor_bind_data        8   (   800)
    -------                    start to json        0   (   800)
    -------                     done to json        1   (   801)
    -------    end get_page_editor_bind_data        0   (   801)
  Rendered ldc/editor/_edit_background.haml (493.1ms)
  Rendered ldc/editor/edit_background.haml within layouts/site_messages (520.1ms)
  Rendered site/_base_dialogs.html.haml (11.6ms)
    -------  call ldc/editor/edit_background       38   (   839)     edit_backg    573
Completed 200 OK in 836.7ms (Views: 550.4ms | ActiveRecord: 98.9ms)
```

log of XHR:

```
--- render if @ [@]
--- render if message_box - not rendered  [@]


Started GET "/ldc/books/288efbc2-98b2-4beb-92de-e5de108cec4d/draw/8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c23-9de3-e7c7ee939fd5?inner=@" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-16 19:34:51 +0300
    -------                       initialize        0   (     0)
Processing by Ldc::BooksController#draw as HTML
  Parameters: {"inner"=>"@", "id"=>"288efbc2-98b2-4beb-92de-e5de108cec4d", "bookpage_id"=>"8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c23-9de3-e7c7ee939fd5"}
say in site_controller.rb:(66) block
            ------- start --------
    -------                            start        0   (     0)
  LoginData Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "login_data".* FROM "login_data" WHERE "login_data"."id" = '0c439950-b8d6-4b8a-9d39-2b2e51a4a291' LIMIT 1
say in checker.rb:(16) initialize
  Ldc::Person Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_people".* FROM "ldc_people" WHERE "ldc_people"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_people"."login_data_id" = '0c439950-b8d6-4b8a-9d39-2b2e51a4a291' LIMIT 1
  Ldc::Bookpage Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_bookpages".* FROM "ldc_bookpages" WHERE "ldc_bookpages"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_bookpages"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c23-9de3-e7c7ee939fd5"]]
    -------  call ldc/editor/edit_background        0   (   273)
######
{:locals=>{}}
{:locals=>{}}
    -------        call ldc/editor/book_page      443   (   716)
    -------     start render partial book_page (#<Ldc::PageTemplates::Defau      234   (   951)
    -------    --ClassicDefaultDefault---- start bookpage 8fe00ae1-c9d2-4c2        0   (   951)
    -------               start to css pre:         0   (   951)
    -------                     done analyse        0   (   951)
    -------           done cibo_template.css        0   (   951)
    -------                           555555       15   (   966)
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup        0   (   966)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup        0   (   966)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup        0   (   966)
    -------           render partial group:         0   (   966)
    -------             start with paragroup      819   (  1786)
   (0.0ms)  select textable_id as id, role, text
...
    -------               end with paragroup        0   (  1786)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (21.2ms)
    -------              done partial group:        0   (  1786)          group    819
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup        0   (  1786)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup       15   (  1802)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup        0   (  1802)
    -------             start with paragroup      795   (  2597)
    -------               end with paragroup       15   (  2613)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (15.7ms)
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup        0   (  2613)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup       15   (  2629)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup        0   (  2629)
    -------             start with paragroup      776   (  3405)
    -------               end with paragroup       15   (  3421)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (15.6ms)
  Ldc::Pageelement Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pageelements".* FROM "ldc_pageelements" WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pageelements"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "da4584dd-ea18-4f14-a321-1e2628efe0c9"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  UPDATE "ldc_pageelements" SET "element_position" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2017-08-16 16:34:55.110874', "paragroup_order" = '211cfcc6-3ce5-4c3f-b001-2230a76cc8903568750-4cc5-45ca-879e-1fa214921d12' WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."id" = 'da4584dd-ea18-4f14-a321-1e2628efe0c9'
   (15.6ms)  commit transaction
    -------        start-1 prepare_paragroup       15   (  3436)
    -------           in A prepare_paragroup       15   (  3452)
    -------           done prepare_paragroup       15   (  3468)
    -------             start with paragroup      753   (  4221)
    -------               end with paragroup       15   (  4237)
  Rendered ppa_data/templates/classic/default/_dg_tables.haml (15.6ms)
  Ldc::Pageelement Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pageelements".* FROM "ldc_pageelements" WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pageelements"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "a27f1ca2-d136-4aef-a486-24772766c04f"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  UPDATE "ldc_pageelements" SET "element_position" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2017-08-16 16:34:55.927238', "paragroup_order" = 'dd7489ce-0b22-40dc-81ab-072de59b7357' WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."id" = 'a27f1ca2-d136-4aef-a486-24772766c04f'
   (15.6ms)  commit transaction
  Ldc::Pageelement Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pageelements".* FROM "ldc_pageelements" WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pageelements"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "9e09e934-50a7-41eb-94df-7355b1d3306c"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  UPDATE "ldc_pageelements" SET "element_position" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2017-08-16 16:34:55.942873', "paragroup_order" = '' WHERE "ldc_pageelements"."id" = '9e09e934-50a7-41eb-94df-7355b1d3306c'
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
    -------    done   get_page_elements_html       15   (  4253)
  Ldc::Page Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ldc_pages".* FROM "ldc_pages" WHERE "ldc_pages"."ustate" = 'A' AND "ldc_pages"."id" = 'dcc8a707-c1c4-4f68-9973-e4c7f0746546' LIMIT 1
  Rendered ldc/editor/_book_page.haml (3301.8ms)
    -------        call ldc/editor/book_page        0   (  4253)           page   3536
    -------               start to css pre:         0   (  4253)
    -------                     done analyse        0   (  4253)
    -------               start to css pre:         0   (  4253)
    -------                     done analyse       15   (  4268)
    -------  start get_page_editor_bind_data        0   (  4268)
    -------                    start to json        0   (  4268)
    -------                     done to json        0   (  4268)
    -------    end get_page_editor_bind_data        0   (  4268)
  Rendered ldc/editor/_edit_background.haml (3574.3ms)
  Rendered ldc/editor/edit_background.haml within layouts/site_messages (3825.1ms)
  Rendered site/_base_dialogs.html.haml (0.0ms)
    -------  call ldc/editor/edit_background      238   (  4507)     edit_backg   4233
Completed 200 OK in 4507.1ms (Views: 4202.6ms | ActiveRecord: 90.6ms)
```

Comment: you should show us parts of your server console - how request and rendering are going... Without that we can't help you. (and I don't believe in magic)

Comment: @MikhailMorgunov: here they are ...

Comment: I'd love to know if GC is running during this lengthy render time.

Comment: garbage collector? how to determine? Force a collect before start of render?

Comment: You could try and enable newrelic in your development instance and gather some data with it. It could help you understand where the bottleneck is. For instance, it could be a database thing. Your production database should be much powerful than your development one. If, in development,  you are hitting some memory limit and your DBMS ends up querying the mass storage to fullfill your queries, that could explain those lenghty response times that do not happen in production.

Comment: You are asking us to explain what is wrong, but you are leaving out what is usually the most significant clue, the code. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)". This occurs in development only? What is the difference between that server and the production server? What happens if you temporarily enable production mode on the development server? When updating your question don't use "edited" or "updated" tags because we can tell when and what changed. Instead add it where it would have been initially.
and the linked pages.

Comment: Also "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"
and "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" are important.

Comment: I bet this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for https://github.com/tmm1/stackprof

I'd write a test or 3 (and cut out the browser - just use standard test tools) and run stackprof on it.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball .. I don't get it.  I'm not with github and I don't think I've ever contributed to stackprof.  Though I'd totally brag if I had contributed to it - it's a super useful tool.